# how to retrieve gender from google sign-in SDK?

Tags: googlesigninaccount, google-signin

I followed that sample: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people

and could successfully login with google.
I can retrieve these data:

```
profile.getId(), 
profile.getName(), 
profile.getGivenName(),
profile.getEmail(),
profile.getImageUrl()
```

But.. how can I retrieve the gender of the user ?

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve the gender using  `Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.Data.Userinfoplus.Gender`

More information click [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/oauth2/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Oauth2_1_1v2_1_1Data_1_1Userinfoplus.html)